# Watson Dialog tutorial file seems to be incorrect

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-dialog

I'm working through the watson dialog tutorial.  I am trying to complete the second step, that creates the example 'excercise_2_end.xml'.

I could not get it to work, so I downloaded and used the given 'excercise_2_end.xml' file, and it also appears to be broken, though I cannot see why (I haven't worked with XML in this way before).

The output from the dialog when run via the bluemix 'work with dialogs' tools is as follows;

> Hello, welcome to Mike’s Pizza
>
> What do you sell?
>
> Are you looking for appetizers, entrees, or drinks?
>
> drinks
>
> I am sorry, I did not understand your question. Please try asking
>   another one.

Where I am expecting;

> Hello, welcome to Mike’s Pizza
>
> What do you sell?
>
> Are you looking for appetizers, entrees, or drinks?
>
> drinks
>
> We have
>   Coke, Sprite, Sunkist, Root Beer, Ginger Ale, Fresca, Mello Yello, Grape, Dr Pepper, Monster, Moxie Energy, and Bottled Spring water

I am using the downloaded example_2_end.xml file, though I also have the same problem with my own that I have created alongside the example.

Any pointers much appreciated :)

Comment: You should look at Watson Conversation instead. It is a much more powerful version of dialog, with a UI. Demo is here: https://vimeo.com/176143934

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem, just by looking into the example_3 file.  There are missing 'getUserInput' nodes from the excersise_2_end file.